# Is there any exotic smooth structure on open hyperbolic manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I edited my post to clarify some confusions as suggested by Igor.

Let $M$ be an open hyperbolic manifold, with or without finite volume, Is there any manifold  $N$ which is homeomorphic to $M$ but not diffeomorphic to $M$?

If $M$ is a closed hyperbolic manifold, then such $N$ exists by constructions of Gromov-Thurston and Farrell-Jones. Farrell-Jones' construction is based on the certain finite cover of a hyperbolic manifold connected sum with exotic sphere. However such construction does not work for open manifolds. So the question is: is there any such exotic examples?

Comment: Your question is confused in several ways. Normally the term "hyperbolic manifold" is reserved for a manifold equipped with a complete hyperbolic metric. Ignoring dimension $2$, by Mostow rigidity there are no exotic finite volume hyperbolic manifolds. Farrell-Jones construct complete negatively pinched manifolds of finite volume that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to hyperbolic ones. For open manifolds their construction is in [J. Differential Geom. 38, No. 2 (1993), 235-261], see http://projecteuclid.org.prx.library.gatech.edu/euclid.jdg/1214454295 .

Comment: (cont.)  Gromov-Thurston construct complete negatively pinched manifolds of finite volume manifolds that are not homotopy equivalent to hyperbolic ones, so their work is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks, JDG's paper is exactly what I want.

Comment: There are (infinitely many) exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, so when $M = \mathbb{H}^4$ you have an example. Or is it your question whether for *every* $M$ there exists an $N$? (In that case, you must at least exclude dimensions 2 and 3, as well as $\mathbb{H}^n$ for $n\neq 4$.)

Comment: As Marco mentions, the answer is clearly yes.